Netbeans on my computer, the JDatechooser-component on the palette shows an empty icon with a question mark
enter image description hereI installed it correctly according to the clip, but still can't use it. The icon has a question mark, and when dragged and dropped, it can't be used. What could be the problem? And when I try to use another library, it doesn't work, and the icon shows a question mark again.(my netbeans ide version 21 and jcalender version 1.4)
Has anyone encountered this issue before? What causes it, and how can it be fixed?
